# What does OleDbParameter srcColumn Parameter do?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, database, vb.net

I have the following code:

```
.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@FY", OleDbType.Integer, 4, _
            ParameterDirection.Input, True, 0, 0, "iYear2000", DataRowVersion.Current, _
            iYear))
```

iYear2000 is the "srcColumn" paramter.

Based on MSDN :

```
Gets or sets the name of the source column mapped to the DataSet and used for loading or returning the Value. (Overrides DbParameter.SourceColumn.)
```

Question is what srcColumn exactly does. In my tests no matter what value I give to this paramter (examples :"ABC", "2000", "HappynewYear" )

I always get same results. When I look at the returned dataset(by the stored procedure) I always see

```
iYear
2000
2001
2002
```

Comment: There is some relevant code missing (e.g. the query you're sending to the `OleDbCommand`).

Comment: Did you look at the examples linked from the "Remarks" section of the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbparameter.sourcecolumn%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

Comment: Yes I did, still i have a hard time understand the effect of source column.

Comment: `Public Sub CreateOleDbParameter() Dim parameter As New OleDbParameter("Description", OleDbType.VarChar, 88) parameter.SourceColumn = "Description" End Sub 'CreateOleDbParameter`

Comment: The `SourceColumn` property is only used with the insert/update/delete commands of a `DataAdapter`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bbw6zyha.aspx

Comment: guys your comments are usefull but I need a working,example of using sourecolumn.